# CSS Dropdown in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have my navigation in CSS so on hover on the main navigation the `<ul>` within a `<li>` parent appears. Simple enough. It works in all browsers, except IE. And I can not figure out why.

Here is the CSS and HTML:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <a href="#" class="nav"><li id="first">Home</li></a>
    <a href="#" class="nav"><li id="second">About
        <ul>                    <a href="#1"><li>Who Am I?</li></a>
            <a href="#2"><li>My Mission</li></a>
            <a href="#3"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
        </ul>
    </li></a>
    <a href="#" class="nav"><li id="third">Toy Box
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Projects</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Toys</li></a>
        </ul>
    </li></a>
    <a href="#" class="nav"><li id="fourth">Contact</li></a>
    <a <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ echo "href='editProfile.php'"; }else{ echo "href='login.php'"; } ?> class="nav"><li id="fifth">Account
        <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        ?>
        <ul>
            <a href="login.php"><li>Log-In</li></a>
            <a href="register.php"><li>Register</li></a>
        </ul>
        <?php
        }else{
        ?>
        <ul>
            <a href="editProfile.php"><li>Edit Profile</li></a>
            <a href="logout.php"><li>Log-Out</li></a>
        </ul>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </li></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

CSS: (In LESS format)

```
ul{
        list-style-type: none;

        li{
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

            font-size: 20px;
            color: #FFF;
            line-height: 35px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: fade(#FFF, 15%);
            .transition-duration(.5s);

            ul{
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                left: -9999px;
                .transition-duration(.3s);

                li{
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 35px;
                    line-height: 35px;
                    background-color: fade(#FFF, 40%);
                }
            }

            &#first:hover{
                background-color: #4200AA;
            }
            &#second:hover{
                background-color: #003BB1;
                ul{
                    left: auto;
                    background-color: #003BB1;
                    .drop-shadow(0px, 2px, 4px, 3px, #111, 30%);
                    li{
                        &:hover{
                            background-color: lighten(#003BB1, 10%);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            &#third:hover{
                background-color: #00BC48;
                ul{
                    left: auto;
                    background-color: #00BC48;
                    .drop-shadow(0px, 2px, 4px, 1px, #111, 30%);
                    li{
                        &:hover{
                            background-color: lighten(#00BC48, 5%);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            &#fourth:hover{
                background-color: @yellow;
                ul{
                    left: auto;
                    background-color: @yellow;
                    .drop-shadow(0px, 2px, 4px, 1px, #111, 30%);
                    li{
                        &:hover{
                            background-color: lighten(@yellow, 10%);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            &#fifth:hover{
                background-color: #E82B15;
                ul{
                    left: auto;
                    background-color: #E82B15;
                    .drop-shadow(0px, 2px, 4px, 1px, #111, 30%);
                    li{
                        &:hover{
                            background-color: lighten(#E82B15, 10%);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which IE version? What exactly does not work? Is it just the transition? Not supported in IE below version 10.

Comment: The older versions of IE do not support `:hover` on list elements.

Comment: Maybe you should try to order your html properly? It's not allowed to insert `a` directly into `ul`. It should contain `li` directly, so proper list would look like `<ul><li><a></a></li></ul>` not the way you did it. I bet older versions of IE could have some problems with such entry.

Comment: And the `a` tags are usually inside the `li` instead of the reverse.

Comment: Let me answer all questions here:
1) All Version of IE have this issue
2) I am not really worried about old versions, just 9 and 10 (Maybe 8)
3 & 4) I have it as `<ul><a><li></li></a></ul>` so that the whole li block is linked, not just the text. However, that seems to be the issue. Any idea how to fix it, so the whole block is clickable, not just text?

Comment: Rearange it as stated above and set the `a` as `display:block;` and the desired size.

Comment: Someone answer this question with that information and I will mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<a href="#"><li></li></a>
```

To

```
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
```

And set the `a` to `display: block;` and the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML with same css

```
<ul>
<a href="#" class="nav"><li id="first">Home</li></a>
<a href="#" class="nav"><li id="second">About
    <ul>                    <a href="#1"><li>Who Am I?</li></a>
        <a href="#2"><li>My Mission</li></a>
        <a href="#3"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
    </ul>
</li></a>
<a href="#" class="nav"><li id="third">Toy Box
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Projects</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Toys</li></a>
    </ul>
</li></a>
<a href="#" class="nav" ><li id="fourth">Contact</li></a>
<a <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ echo "href='editProfile.php'"; }else{ echo "href='login.php'"; } ?> <a href="#" class="nav"><li id="fifth">Account</li></a>
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    ?>
    <ul>
        <a href="login.php"><li>Log-In</li></a>
        <a href="register.php"><li>Register</li></a>
    </ul>
    <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <ul>
        <a href="editProfile.php"><li>Edit Profile</li></a>
        <a href="logout.php"><li>Log-Out</li></a>
    </ul>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</li></a>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Didn't change anything. Can you explain what you changed? Because I can't see anything.

Comment: Your "nav" Account section was not held under any tag so it was showing as it is in the browser.

Comment: Yes it was PHP started the a tag, then the li. then the li and a close AFTER I announce the drop down content.

Comment: oh i see, but somehow the code written in that <a> tag is not working in my browser.

Comment: Do you have the code running on your localhost with a PHP Server? If not it won't work, you can't just run it.